# Android Annotations - Event binding on item created in code

Tags: java, android, event-handling, android-annotations

I'm using Android annotations for my project. 
I try to add en event on buttons created in code.

I have several buttons, and try to add a Focus Change event on them, to have something like this :

```
@FocusChange(?)
protected void buttonFocusChanged(View btn, boolean hasFocus) {
//Some cool animation
}
```

This sample code does not work, because my buttons haven't any Resource ID, and I can find how to use annotations without the Resource ID.

Can I use the annotations for this, or should I use the "normal" method, and do this for each button :

```
beautifulButton.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {  
     //Some ugly animation
   }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can use the annotated thing. The event listener will be added in `onCreate()` in case of `Activity`, and in `onViewCreated()` in case of `Fragment`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, when I put the above code, I got an error because the workaround of Android Annotations. I don't have any ID for the dynamically created button, so I can't use `@FocusChange(R.id.mybuttonID)` method, or the other method, where the name is used to find a associated ID ("button" in the code sample), same problem, the buttons doesn't have ID.

Comment: If the buttons do not have an ID, then you cannot use the annotations.

Comment: Thanks a lot WonderCsabo !